# Button in Relative Layout gets squished when setting margins

Tags: java, android, random, android-relativelayout

I am randomizing the location of a button on a Relative View everytime a button is clicked. I am doing this by changing the margins of the buttons programatically as shown in the code:

```
 Button testbtn = findViewById(R.id.testbtn);
    testbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Get Screen size
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            //Save dimensions in variables
            int widthScreen = metrics.widthPixels;
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            TextView width_height = findViewById(R.id.width_height);


            //Declare random
            Random randomDimension = new Random();

            //Declare layout params
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.rightMargin = 608; 
            params.leftMargin = 428; 
            params.topMargin = randomDimension.nextInt(height) +1;
            //params.setMargins();
            buttonIDs[1].setLayoutParams(params);

            width_height.setText(params.leftMargin+" "+params.rightMargin);

        }
    });
```

In this case, "buttonIDs[]" is an array i declared earlier in the class and "testbtn" is the button that when pressed, randomizes the position of my button.

However, these specific margins produce the following image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gPBn.jpg)

and I need:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ddc.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You set:

```
    params.rightMargin = 608; 
    params.leftMargin = 428;
```

So the device must be `608+428+width of the button` at least wide. Is it?

Comment: It is not, I thought that the left and right margins were points on the screen where I wanted the button sides to be placed. I did not know that the margins would get added together

Comment: This is the case. So you can use `leftMargin` and `topMargin` to position the views